# How do you preserve symlinks in a GIT repo?

Tags: linux, git

I have symlinks to several folders in my project, in a GIT repo. When I clone the repo elsewhere on another server, the symlinks aren't preserved and become files.

On that server, I tried setting the global setting for "core.symlinks=true" before cloning, but that didn't help.

How do I preserve the symlinks in the repo?

Comment: The way Git is supposed to work is that if your OS / filesystem is capable of storing symbolic links at all, Git will re-create them automatically. The `core.symlinks` setting is the result of Git probing your system to *find out* if symlinks work: it's set to `true` if they do and `false` if they don't. If Git has set this to false, Git believes your system *can't* create symlinks.

Comment: I tried initiating git, setting it locally, then cloning the repo in the current folder, but it wouldn't let me clone since I already initialized in this folder (it said the folder was not empty). So I wiped out the .git folder so I could clone it, but then the GIT settings were gone so the setting wasn't active at the time. How do I set the setting, then pull? The process isn't clear to me.

Comment: `git init` creates a new, empty repository, setting `core.symlinks` according to Git's measure of your file system's ability to create symbolic links. `git clone` creates a new repository similarly (and uses the same code to set `core.symlinks`) but then populates that new repository from some existing repository. Either way Git sets `core.symlinks` during the creation of the repository.

Comment: If you want to test overriding Git's own decision, you can `git init` an empty repository, adjust `core.symlinks` manually, then do the rest of the steps that `git clone` would do: `git remote add origin <url>`, `git fetch origin`, and `git checkout <branch>` (`<branch>` is usually `master`).

Comment: Thanks torek. I tried it, but then it said:
error: unable to create symlink assets/folder1/mysymlinkname: No such file or directory
Checking out files: 100% (6866/6866), done.
D        assets/folder1/mysymlinkname

Actually, one of the symlinks worked, the one that was at the root. The ones that were inside subdirectories failed

Comment: So is it even possible to have the symlinks that are inside of subdirectories to work? Or only those at the root?

Comment: On a Linux ext2, ext3, ext4, zfs, etc., file system, symbolic links should just work. On a Windows NT-FS file system, symbolic links might be optional (I understand they do exist there). On some other file systems, symbolic links are simply not an option. So the question here is what kind of mount point(s) do you have on your Linux system? (Or, if it's not a Linux system, what kind of system *is* it and what capabilities does that file system offer?)

Comment: Is it the system where the symlinks were first created that matters, or the system that is cloning the repo? The system I'm cloning on is on a HostGator shared server: 3.10.0-693.11.6.1.ELK.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux, nano-2.0.9-7.el6.x86_64. Should symlinks work here?

Comment: As long as the files are actually `120000 blob <hash> <path>` in the tree (use `git ls-tree` to view the committed tree), what matters is the system that is cloning the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer, but this works for windows

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true <URL>
```